# check if hdd has bad sectors ad force windows to ignore them

Tags: windows-7, bsod, bad-sectors, hard-drive-recovery, bad-blocks

i have a 500gb hdd (SeaGate), and every now and then i get a bsod with error being ntfs.sys

it happens daily, maybe even 3 times a day

is there a way I can check if my hdd has:

**a.** A bad sector/s

**b.** if a, can I force windows to ignore these bad sectors?

***please note:*** I have already done SMART tests with seatools which passed

thnx I would really appreciate any help

Comment: You say it passed but how many reallocated sectors are there? The hdd itself will ignore bad sectors. Of course if you already have a high amount of bad sectors which is determined by the reallocated sector count telling Windows to ignore bad sectors is sort of pointless because new bad sectors will appear.  [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/47410/hard-drive-bad-sector-marking-utility?rq=1) are some suggestions that helps the hdd determine what sectors are good and what sectors are bad

Comment: how am i able to avoid this bsod of ntfs.sys in the future? that is besides a replacement hdd?

Comment: I need the information I asked for.  I also provided a link that has tools to help the HDD help itself deal with reallocated and bad sectors.  In the end this problem normally points to a possible future drive failure.  At this point its passing the tests, because it has not reached the thresholds, the firmware considers to be bad.